# Why does deleting this element with a non-unique ID delete the one I want?

Tags: javascript, html

Pardon the bad title, it's hard to explain. If you know how to phrase it better, please comment and I will update as soon as I can.

So, I was messing around with a random generator site ([perchance.org](https://perchance.org)) and writing my own HTML/Javascript to make my generator work. It has a behavior that is what I want, but that shouldn't be happening according to my knowledge of HTML.
Let me explain with a minimal example.

The example code here is to produce a simple page that has a button.
This button should generate <input>s with <button>s next to them, attached with similar ID's.
The button, when clicked, deletes the <input> and <button>.

Here is a snippet to show you the code/let you reproduce the results:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var current_id = 0;
      
      function add_input () {
        var list = document.getElementById("list");
      
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var delete_button = document.createElement("button");
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        
        input.id = "input_" + current_id;
        delete_button.id = "button_" + current_id;
        br.id = "br_" + current_id;
        
        input.value = input.id;
        delete_button.textContent = "Delete";
        
        delete_button.onclick = function () {
          delete_input(this.id.slice(7)) //To get the numerical ID
        }
        
        list.appendChild(input);
        list.appendChild(delete_button);
        list.appendChild(br);
        
        current_id++;
      }
      
      function delete_input (id) {
        var input = document.getElementById("input_"+id);
        var button = document.getElementById("button_"+id);
        var br = document.getElementById("br_"+id);
        
        input.remove();
        button.remove();
        br.remove();
        
        current_id--;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="list">
  
  </div>
  <button onclick="add_input()">Add</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you add two inputs, then delete the first, and add one more, it leaves you with two inputs using the same ID. It also leaves you with two buttons with the same ID. And yet, both buttons delete their intended target.

**Why?**

Comment: If there are same IDs, the first occurance of ID is removed.

Comment: It doesn't always remove a correct element. Add ex. `new Date().getSeconds()` to the input values, then you'll see the code fails to pick the wanted input.

Comment: This is easily solved by not doing the `current_id--;` in the `delete_input()` function. By subtracting from the `current_id`, you make it possible to make multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: @Samathingamajig I understand how to fix it **if** it needed it. My question is why does this work (even if it is terrible practice).

Comment: @Teemu I see, but why is that? In the execution I used it for, it seemed to work fine (user-inputted strings).

Comment: @pavel But in this instance, it deletes either input, depending on which delete button you press, which means **both** have the ID.

Comment: @FuzzyMuffin What do you mean "why does it work"? It doesn't work. See this case: Click the add button 5 times. Delete "input_0" and "input_1". Click the add button two more times. Click the delete button by the second "input_3". It deletes the first "input_3" instead of the second "input_3". To show this even more, click the delete button of the second "input_4". It deletes the first "input_4" instead of the second. Therefore, this does not "work". This is expected to happen because of how `document.getElementById()` works: it always finds the first element with that id.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Ah, I see. I also realize the original example was also not working (although it was working in my actual usage - I changed it already, but it is still confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

You really should delegate - here I wrap in a div that can be removed in one go

You can rename each input to have incremented IDs but just letting the cnt run, gives you unique IDs

```js
let cnt = 0;
function add_input() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var delete_button = document.createElement("button");
  var br = document.createElement("br");

  input.id = "input_" + (cnt++)// list.querySelectorAll("div").length
  input.value = input.id;

  delete_button.textContent = "Delete";
  delete_button.classList.add("delete")

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(delete_button);
  div.appendChild(br);

  list.appendChild(div);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) tgt.closest("div").remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
<button onclick="add_input()">Add</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, and will decide if I want to add them, but my question wasn't about why it wasn't working, or even how to make it better. My question was *why* the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to be more effective.

I'm not using IDs as they aren't adding any benefit instead making it more complex.

Instead I target the element via the event handler and an argument.

I also wrap each set of inputs/buttons in a div so I can just remove that div and it will remove all of the children.

```js
function add_input() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var delete_button = document.createElement("button");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  delete_button.textContent = "Delete";

  delete_button.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }

  var div = document.createElement("div");

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(delete_button);
  div.appendChild(br);

  list.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
<button onclick="add_input()">Add</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate the good, clean code here and realize it is much better. However, my question wasn't about why it wasn't working, or even how to make it better. My question was *why* the code works.